# Amazon DynamoDB and Provisioned Throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and I'm having trouble getting my head around the Provisioned Throughput.

From what I've read it seems you can use this to set the limit of reads and writes at one time. Have I got that wrong?

Basically what I want to do is store emails that are sent through my software. I currently store them in a MySQL database but the amount of data is very large which is why I am looking at DynamoDB. This data I do not need to access very often but when it's needed, I need to be able to access it.

Last month 142,925 emails were sent and each "row" (or email) in the MySQL table I store them in is around 2.5KB.

Sometimes 1 email is sent, other times there might be 3,000 at one time. There's no way of knowing when or how many will be sent at any given time.

Do you have any suggestions on what my Throughputs should be?

And if I did go over, am I correct in understanding that Amazon throttles it and adds them over time? Or does it just throw and error and that's the end of it?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using DynamoDB with the Java SDK. When you have an access burst, amazon first tries to keep up, even allowing a bit above the provisioned throughput, after that it start throttling and also throws exceptions. In our code we use this error to break the requests into smaller batches and sometimes force a sleep to cool it down a bit.

When dealing with your situation it really depends on the type of crunching you need to do "from time to time". How much time do you need to get all the data from the table? do you really need to get all of it? And ~100k a month doesn't sound too much for MySQL in my mind.. it all depends on the querying power you need.

Also note that in DynamoDB writes are more expensive than reads so maybe that alone signals that it is not the best fit for your write-intensive problem.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDb is very expensive, I would suggest not to store emails in dynamo db as each read and write cost good amount, Basically 1 read unit means 4KB data read per sec and 1 write unit means 1KB data write per sec, As you mentioned your each email is 2.5KB, hence while searching data(if you dont have proper key for searching the email) table will be completely scanned that will cost a very good amount as you will need several write units for reading.