# How to keep a DynamoDb query within provisioned throughput?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDb has provisioned data throughput limits and based on the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362775/amazon-dynamodb-and-provisioned-throughput) it appears that if you exceed your throughput limits DynamoDb can start throwing exceptions, rather than just slowing your query down. If you run a query (e.g. as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html)), how do you ensure the query doesn't exceed the throughputs?

A query will be automatically limited to 1 MB in which case you have to do some tricky re-querying using the LastEvaluatedKey as described in their docs (with no code example). However dependent on the query speed or similar even this 1 MB could presumably blow your provisioned limits?

You can also set the maximum number of items returned in the QuerySpec object so you then process the query in individual pages - which I'm guessing do separate queries under the hood. However if you don't know the size of your items in-advance, you can't limit it by number of KB as needed to stay within the throughput. Chicken and egg situation.

Am I missing something here? Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by following solutions or by combining the solutions

**Solution 1:** As you have stated in your question if you know your Item size you can Limit the number of records, pass the `lastEvaluatedKey` to get next set of records.

Again even this might be enough to throttle your limits, you need to have a sleep  mechanism for a while so that you wont hit the table continuously.

**Solution 2:** By far the best method I have implement is that don't hit the DynamoDB table rather store your information in some form of cache(`Memcahce`, `Elasticache`, etc)

This will ensure that you wont require very high throughput rate.

**Note:** This will depend on your type of application as well if your data is updated very frequently than this might not be very helpful.